# DLError (Exec format error) Ruby26-x64 trying to open python.dll

Tags: ruby, dll

I'm trying to open python.dll with ruby but I'm getting the following error with the following line of code

```
Fiddle.dlopen("C:\\Python36/lib/python.dll").tap
Traceback (most recent call last):
        8: from C:/Ruby26-x64/bin/irb.cmd:31:in `<main>'
        7: from C:/Ruby26-x64/bin/irb.cmd:31:in `load'
        6: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/irb-1.0.0/exe/irb:11:in `<top (required)>'
        5: from (irb):7
        4: from (irb):7:in `rescue in irb_binding'
        3: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/fiddle.rb:47:in `dlopen'
        2: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/fiddle.rb:47:in `new'
        1: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/fiddle.rb:47:in `initialize'
Fiddle::DLError (Exec format error)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your Python/Ruby install are of the same bits.